# Database connection leak caused by new spring transaction in jboss

Tags: java, spring, jboss

We have a REST service deployed on a jboss server. Until recently, we only had one transaction configured, and that was at the service layer. So either, the transaction was successful and everything was committed or everything was rolled back if there was an exception.

We have now started adding a record to a table even if the service returns a failure response. To achieve this, we have added an annotation to the api used by the rest service:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

This means that if we throw an exception from the service, the row is saved to the database.

However, since we have added this new transaction, we have got a connection leak, and I can see this in the logs:

> javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed
>   connection for java:/jdbc/xxx at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
>   at
>   org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:69)

I guess that the committed connection isn't being released when there is an exception. Is there some extra config required?

Comment: How do you save the row if you have an exception? It probably means that the data is not correct, no?

Comment: Without looking at the code, I've made the mistake of calling another method in the same class and forgetting it will not pick up the @Transactional annoation.

Comment: @NiVeR we are updating some details about the user in the database. The exception is caused because they have entered invalid details, and we want to track that.